# Redirect domain.com/index.php/xyz to domain.com/xyz

Tags: redirect

Hi I have used following for index.php redirect to homepage (and its working)

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

I want its subpages also get redirect example index.php/xyz  to home/xyz

Please help me how to modify the above code

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the end of your rules:

RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) $1 [NS,NC,L,R=301]